# Not able to find location field for this particular site "http://www.macys.com/"

Tags: java, httpurlconnection

I have the following site : "http://www.macys.com/" for which there is redirection.

This is code snippet:

```java
String location = "http://www.macys.com/";
do {
    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    try {
        url = location;
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        /**
         * Setting the Browser properties
         */
        conn.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76 Safari/537.36");
        conn.setConnectTimeout(2000);
        conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
        conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
        conn.connect();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Exception : {}", e.getMessage());
    }

    responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();

    if ((responseCode > 300 && responseCode < 310)) {
        location = connection.getHeaderField("Location");
        if (location == null)
            break;
    }
} while (responseCode > 300 && responseCode < 310);
```

After first iteration, response code is 302, but no location field is found.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The server is not configured correctly it seems. The "Location" header is missing even when just accessing the website from your browser, your java code is not fault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the response body, you can see that the site is denying your request.

`Access Denied: You don't have permission to access the requested URL on this server.`

The site won't send you a `Location` header despite showing response code of 302 when they deny you access.